# Power layout for robot from 42 V to multiple output voltages

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, robot

Most real robots will need to provide different voltage levels, i.e 5 V for MCU, 12 V for actuators, 19 V for PC/NUC 24 V etc. They also need to monitor charging and discharging of batteries.

I searched a while to find a ready product, or at least a DC-DC converter with multiple output without success. I would prefer one PCB or DC-DC converter for multiple outputs instead of multiple devices, one for each single output.

The robot gets powered by 10S 18650 battery, so in total 42 V.

Main PC will need 19 V with up to 100 W. Motors will run off 42 V directly but other components need other voltage levels. I.e. 24 V 6 A

I know this is not a specific question but it would help me a lot to understand how others solve this.

BR Patrick

This is a cross post, initially posted at robotics.stackexchange. Someone mentioned to post here as well to get a better result.

Comment: There are multi-output power management ICs but those are oriented toward generation of multiple logic-level voltage rails, such as 5V, 3.3V, 3.0V, 2.5V, 1.8V, 1.2V.  The ones I've seen support monitoring and control (programming voltages, turning individual channels on or off) through I2C / SMBus.  Your need sounds a little different from that.

Comment: The power requirements for each output voltage are quite substantial so it’s unlikely you’ll find a single device that will provide exactly what you want.  But using multiple DC-DC devices means you can situate them near point-of-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to create multiple voltage rails, one option is to use a power management controller (PMIC).  [This particular example](https://www.maxlinear.com/product/power-management/universal-pmics/universal-pmics/xrp7740) takes a 6.5-20V input and creates up to 4 output rails with whatever voltages you want.  [This one](https://www.nxp.com/products/power-management/pmics-and-sbcs/safety-sbcs/high-voltage-pmic-with-multiple-smps-and-ldo-primary-companion-chip-for-s32rx:FS5502) can take an input up to 60V, but the output voltage options are more restricted.  They come in many varieties, so you should be able to find one to match your specific needs.  Many also let you control power *sequencing* (i.e., let this device turn on first, then bring up that rail, etc).

It seems unlikely that you'd find one that *also* did battery monitoring. You will most likely need a separate device for that.

Comment: Thanks for brining me to PMIC. Now I have a keyword to search for